# JWT auth token undefined

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm trying to implement jwt auth and it's work fine in Postman but react don't see value of response.

```
login = () => {
       ...
        .then(res => {
            const jwtToken = res.accessToken;
            console.log(jwtToken);
            if (jwtToken !== null) {
                sessionStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, jwtToken);
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});

            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
};
```

Back end get request properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are u using axios or directly fetch?

if you are using fetch, try this:

```
fetch('endpoint)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Try to see whats inside data, if your backend works properly, you should see the accessToken property in that object.